# I have two string having same content but having different hashcode, hence .equals method is retruning false. Please advice how to solve this

Tags: java

```
  for (String header : headers) {
            for (int i = 0; i < dataList.get(0).size(); i++) {
                String s = dataList.get(0).get(i);
                String h = header;
                int h1 = s.hashCode();
                int h2 = h.hashCode();
                int n = s.compareTo(h);
                if (s.equals(h)) {
                    for (int k = 1; k < dataList.size(); k++) {
                        values.add(dataList.get(k).get(i));
                    }
```

Here "headers" in for loop is => String[] headers containing 6 String objects.

I have also tried with intern method and also storing those values in new String object. Every time equals method is returning false.
If anyone has any idea please share, it will be a great help to me!!

[image]
[Link of Screenhot for code while debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMRQ2.png)

Comment: Please see the image in "enter image description here". click on that link, you will find the code in that image as it was a screenshot.

Comment: Welcome to SO. [edit] and Copy-and-paste the code into the question. Don't upload images (or links to images) of code. [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Comment: You should better add the code using copy-paste, thus can people see it better and even try to use it

Comment: The obvious answer is that your hashcode needs to return the same value for identical content.  But we'd need your code in the question to understand, and you've posted an image instead.  Please edit and update your question.

Comment: The obvious answer is that the two strings don't have the same content. Although they look the same on screen, one of the characters is actually different, or an invisible character is present in one of them and not the other. Print the numeric value of each character of each string, and you'll see what the difference is.

Comment: It could be you have different encoding, or some hidden chars there ...

Comment: The image is from the debugger and does show interesting information beyond the code itself. In any case we would like to have the code *in the question*, not only in a linked image.

Comment: Would you mind evaluating and providing us the result of `s.toCharArray()` and `h.toCharArray()`? You can do so using your debugger when suspended at the same line as you show in your screenshot.

Comment: okk I will do and let you know.
But as in the screen shot you can see both having same content "Name", I also tried using trim(), but still its giving different hashcode for same string

Comment: I just converted the two strings to two different char Array, so first one having 5 characters and second array having 4 characters although they have same content "Name", but only the character which is different, is like as follows:
\uFEFF

Comment: I solved that problem.. Thanks Andrey Akhmetov for sharing that idea, it helped me to detect the roots of the problem, now I solved my problem, please see my answer

Comment: I solved my problem, its due to one unprintable elements, its solved by this method : replaceAll("\p{C}","") 
"\p(C)" it detect where the non printable element is.. then using replaceAll it will replace that nonPrintable element with empty string.

Comment: In case anyone is curious, that char seems to be [an Arabic zero width non-break space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/FEFF/index.htm). Don’t know where you got it from.

Comment: I converted one csv to List<List<Strings>>, I dont know also where it came from. :)

Answer (score 1):

The string `h` has the correct hashcode. 
The string `s` that is read from `dataList` should not produce that hashcode. 
So check it for any inconsistencies. 
Print the ascii code of each of its chars. 
It should give: `78 97 109 101`

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem, its due to one unprintable elements,
its solved by this : replaceAll("\p{C}","")
"\p(C)" it detect where the non printable element is..
then using replaceAll it will replace that nonPrintable element with empty string.